# 301 Redirect with .Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

my htaccess file has these lines:

```
RewriteRule ^newlink ?do=something
Redirect 301 /oldlink/ /newlink
```

when i write **http://www.example.com/oldlink/**, browser redirects to **http://www.example.com/newlink?do=something**

how can i trim **?do=something**  ??

it should redirect to **/newlink**; not **/newlink?do=something**

Comment: ask on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix `mod_rewrite` rules with `mod_alias` ones. Keep your rules using `mod_rewrite` itself like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+newlink[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /?do=something [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+oldlink/?[\s?] [NC]    
RewriteRule ^ /newlink? [L,NC,R=302]
```

`?` in the end is for trimming any existing query string.

Comment: are you sure? it results 500 Internal Server Error...  (/content/ is different from /content; because i use /content for category homepage; /content/link = detail pages)

Comment: thank you anubhava... but, how about if i have tons of(100+) category; such as /content/, /gallery/, /collections/, /news/ etc... isnt it cause too much line in htaccess? cant i do it via 301?

Comment: i will use 301 for only some old url's

Comment: Better you edit your question and add this in your requirements. Stachoverflow mods don't like changing question from comments section.

Comment: could you look again please :/